# Can I "just say, no" to prevent Homebrew installing system-wide paths in /etc/paths.d?

Tags: macos, path, homebrew

I am using the Brewfile method to install a set of packages in macOS version 12.6.6 (Monterey).

I see Homebrew formula are installing files in a system-wide location: `/etc/paths.d`

Sure, macOS will pick those up and modify your PATH variable. I don't want or need that.

I first noticed this when I saw paths appended to the end of my default macOS environment PATH variable `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

After taking a closer look I saw files indicating multiple packages are doing this:

- wireshark
- MacGPG2
- exiftool
- quarto

Does anyone know of a way to stop this during an automated `brew bundle install` ?

I would prefer a Homebrew formula that does not write files in system-wide locations. I can manage my own path locally in my user's home dir.

I am hoping to find a solution to disable this formula behavior so that I don't need to clean up after Homebrew does its job. And it does it well!